# Python script distribution

Tags: python, windows, linux, software-distribution

I'm having some trouble with distributing my python programs. for linux it's easy enough, just tell people which packages they need and provide the source. for windows however it's a different story altogether. I can get my program compiled with py2exe. the problem there however is that it always seems to miss one dll file or the other.

my question therefore is, is there some easy way to package a python script for multiple platforms? right now I keep having to go on a wild goosechase after dll files I don't have. and this isn't even mentioning the 32bit vs. 64bit problem which leaves a lot to desire.

any and all pointers are welcome. the ideal solution would be some sort of script that would create two zipfiles. one being linux/source and one for windows64bit/windows32bit. I really don't care all that much about mac support, but it would be welcome.

Comment: `py2exe` works fine for this purpose.  It isn't easy though - more like pulling teeth.  If you work really hard you can make a `setup.py` which works for windows (py2exe), mac (py2app) and linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you support linux, you probably support mac in the same way.

I typically use py2exe to distribute to windows, but there are alternatives, such as cxfreeze, and others.  I haven't bothered to care much about 64/32 bit and just deliver a 32 bit solution.

Here are a list of packagers:

http://www.freehackers.org/Packaging_a_python_program

Comment: thanks for the answer. and I'm currently using py2exe as well, but the main problem with that is that I need to scour the interwebs for the 32bit dlls since I'm on 64bit. thanks for the link though.

Comment: UPDATE: bbfreeze does seem to do what I need. but I can't get a compiled version for python2.7 on windows. needles to say I can't get a compiler to work on windows either.